# Mssql и Visual Studio не могу обновить процедуру

Tags: c#, sql-server, procedure

Имею процедуру, она выполняется и работает в студии mssql
Я её связал ранее через источник данных с vs проектом.
Потом я изменил её, поменял в селекте имя на паспорт.

```
USE incc;
GO
alter PROCEDURE my_client
@surname nvarchar(30),
@name nvarchar(30)
 AS
BEGIN
select  Klient.surnameKlient as 'Фамилия', Klient.passportKlient as 'Паспорт'
from Сontract
inner join Agent on Agent.id_Agent = Сontract.id_a
inner join Klient on Klient.id_Klient=Сontract.id_k
where Agent.surnameAgent = @surname and Agent.nameAgent = @name
END;
```

И при обновлении процедуры в студии VS у меня появляется ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже не знаю что  и думать туда, вроде все проверил, все есть.
Приложу ещё функцию вызова процедуры, она возвращает таблицу.

```
public void my_client_loadform(DataTable tblEmployees)
        {
            using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(conn))
            using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("my_client", _con))
            {
                _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                _cmd.Parameters["@surname"].Value = surnameAg;
                _cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = nameAg;
                SqlDataAdapter _dap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
                _dap.Fill(tblEmployees);
            }
        }
```

Как собственно решить проблему? Спасибо.

---

РЕШЕНИЕ:

Удалось исправить проблему. До сих пор не понимаю с чем связана ошибка, но решил проблему просто пересоздав процедуру с другими именем, подключив к студии все заработало. Можно эта проблема на уровне ...Designer.cs

Comment: Решений 2: 1-е, понять что логика в MSSQL, вообще-то не самый лучший вариант, и перенести запрос в код, тогда просто конструируете запрос в виде текста и передаете в подключение текст. 2-ой вариант: сделать процедуру без параметра, либо изначально задавать значение параметра в процедуре (т.е. `@surname nvarchar(30),
@name nvarchar(30)
 AS
BEGIN SET @surname=@name=''`) по умолчанию, и использовать как сейчас. Но это с позиции идеалогии, а с позиции синтаксиса, ради эксперимента, задайте имя переменной как  @name1, возможно что вы попали в системное наименование!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, проблему решил путём пересоздания процедуры под другим именем.